# `origyear` in square brackets in front of `year`

Tags: biblatex

I need to meet special design rules for my bibliography so this code was made for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{references={Bibliographie}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
  \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\bibstring{#2}}
    {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}
       {\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\providecommand*{\iflabeldateisdate}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    not test {\iffieldundef{labeldatesource}}
    and 
    (test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{}} 
     or test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{year}})}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\iffieldnum{edition}
            {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
             \global\clearfield{edition}}
            {}%
          \printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}


\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,companion,cotton,iliad,malinowski,
        gaonkar:in,westfahl:space,pines,brandt,hyman,kant:kpv}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now there is one last thing I need: for some publications it is necessary for me to state the year of its first appearance like this:

Doe, Jane [1979] (**2**2003) etc

(the **bold** number is supposed to be in superscript)

Comment: What about citations? Can we just use the normal year there or do you need the `origyear` as well?

Comment: I keep forgetting that everything is possible with LaTeX... for the citations the normal year is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your `date+extrayear` macro to print the `origdate` in the bibliography if it is defined.

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{origdate}% <- add this line
     \setunit*{\addspace}%   <- add this line
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\iffieldnum{edition}
            {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
             \global\clearfield{edition}}
            {}%
          \printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
```

Then define a macro to print the `origdate`.

```
\newbibmacro*{origdate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}}}
```

Putting it all together with your MWE (I added Doe 2003 with an `origyear` of 1979):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{doe,
  author = {Doe, Jane},
  title = {Title},
  edition = {2},
  date = {2003},
  origdate = {1979},
  location = {Location},
  publisher = {Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{references={Bibliographie}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
  \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\bibstring{#2}}
    {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}
       {\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\providecommand*{\iflabeldateisdate}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    not test {\iffieldundef{labeldatesource}}
    and 
    (test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{}} 
     or test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{year}})}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{origdate}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\iffieldnum{edition}
            {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
             \global\clearfield{edition}}
            {}%
          \printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\newbibmacro*{origdate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}


\begin{document}
\cite{doe}
\nocite{sigfridsson,companion,cotton,iliad,malinowski,
        gaonkar:in,westfahl:space,pines,brandt,hyman,kant:kpv}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Though you can move the brackets into the format and drop the `\iffieldundef` with  `\newbibmacro*{origdate}{\printorigdate}
\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}`